# EGit and Git See Different Unstaged Files

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have read all the other questions regarding differences between EGit and Git when it comes to unstaged and dirty files but none of the proposed/accepted solutions worked for me.

I am running Windows 7 and Cygwin. I have an Eclipse workspace in location "C:/Workspace". When in Cygwin, in "/cygdrive/c/Workspace":

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       Temp/bin
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

as **expected** but in Eclipse (Egit), each and every single file is seens as "unstaged":

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse with the Staging view showing all files as "unstaged"]

which is **unexpected**. I tried various solutions, including setting "core.filemode=false". All the files are in the workspace in "C:/Workspace/" and there are no links of any kind. What I am missing?

Comment: Where are your project and files? In `C:/Workspace`? Or elsewhere? Because the proejct could have benn imported in the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, after reading the other questions, I made sure that all the files are in the workspace in "C:/Workspace" and that there are no links of any kind... That's why this problem is puzzling me: it should be the "best case" scenario... (I edited the question to precise where the files are.) Thanks!

Comment: Can you tight click on the project and select Team > Share to see if it recognizes the presence of a git repo, or if it tries to version that project again in a new git repo? Where is the `.git` folder by the way?

Comment: Try setting `core.autocrlf` to `false`.

Comment: @VonC I don't see a "Share" item in the Team context-menu but when checking the properties of one of the project, I see that it is connected to Git with the correct path to the .git file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution suggested by @robinst solves the problem. To avoid such discrepencies between EGit and Git because of the way that Windows and Cygwin deal with CR and LF, the solution is to set the property:

```
core.autocrlf=false
```

Comment: The above is a workaround for [bug 372834 in JGit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372834), which is fixed for version 3.3. So if you are using EGit 3.3 or newer, the original bug should be gone.